# Unable to push-upgrade managed app after deleting packaged VF page

Tags: managed-package, isv, spring15, deprecation

I just tried out the new feature [Streamline Managed Packages by Deleting Unused Components](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_delete_managed_components.htm?edition=&impact=) that came with Spring'15 and deleted a managed VF page called "Advanced Lookup Popup" including its Controller class from my package.

I now push-upgraded an existing customer org and it failed with this error:

> This app can't be upgraded. Salesforce has blocked this package
>   upgrade because the new package version removes some Apex code that
>   one or more Visualforce pages or global Visualforce components need in
>   order to function. Please contact your partner with this error
>   information. Provide these component names to your partner.
>   Visualforce Page: Advanced Lookup Popup.

How can I resolve this? Or is this a bug?

Comment: We just opened a case as we are having the same issue after deleting VF pages and the associated code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We just got this answer from Salesforce.com Support regarding our related case.

There is this knowledge article for this kind of problem [Removing Obsolete Visualforce from Managed Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212807&language=en_US)

**Eric Adding to the answer**

If you have already deleted and packaged up the changes to a new package you will need to follow the below steps to upgrade users to the new package version:

1. Create a patch from the previous version WITH the VF pages
2. In the patch update all VF pages to simply `<apex:page />`
3. Upgrade the customer to the patch version
4. Upgrade the customer to the latest full version with the pages deleted

Basically you need to upgrade to a version with the metadata modified to not reference anything first then you can update to the packages with the metadata deleted.

Comment: Us to. It does not help us resolve the current issue though. Damage is already done and we cannot upgrade our customers.....ugh.. Thanks for the link, a partner alert has just been posted as well

Comment: @Eric is there any solution to this? I can't restore the deleted VF page since it was a full release of the package.

Comment: You can create a patch from the Previous version (and remove all references to the deleted component but leave the component in) where the page existed and install the patch, then you will be able to install the new update where the VF page is removed

Comment: Thanks Eric. It worked. You can create a patch from the Previous version (and remove all references to the deleted component but leave the component in) where the page existed and install the patch, then you will be able to install the new update where the VF page is removed